# ng4 componentFactory placing it in the DOM target

Tags: angular, factory, angular-components

## What I am trying to do

I am working on a vote casting system, which will be reused in multiple components around the website. To keep it dry, I want to create the voting component from any component, into the designated DOM element.. After the component has been created, the instance variables must be set (in this case `model:string` and `pk:number`, both public).

## Expected result

I expect the component to be rendered in the designated location, printing the right data which have been set right after the factory has created the component. The output at the bottom of the votes should be `Model: project PK: 1`

## Actual Situation

The ComponentFactory currently has **two** outputs of the voting component created by the Component factory:

1. On the right location (targeted div), but without the set instance variables.
   [image: image1]
2. On the bottom of the page, but this is an other issue, for a later time and in an other topic.

## Some code

```
@NgModule({
    ..
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        ProjectComponent, // parent for voteContainer
        VoteComponent, // Dynamic component
    ],
    entryComponents: [
        VoteComponent,
    ], ..
})
```

parent component containing the VoteComponent factory

```
export class ProjectDetailComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild('voteComponentContainer', {read: ViewContainerRef}) voteComponentContainer;

    public ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.factoryVoteComponent();
    }

    private factoryVoteComponent() {
        const voteComponentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(VoteComponent);
        const voteComponentRef = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(voteComponentFactory);
        voteComponentRef.instance.model = "project";
        voteComponentRef.instance.pk = 1;
        voteComponentRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    }
}
```

Dynamic component target:

```
<vote-component-container></vote-component-container>
```

Basic voting Component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'vote-component-container',
    templateUrl: 'vote.component.html',
})

export class VoteComponent {
    public model:string;
    public pk:number;
    public constructor(){}
}
```

## What I have tried

I have been struggling with this for quite a while now, so there
are quite some attempts to get it to work. The final attempt was
with creating the ViewChild for the factory.

Besides that, I've been playing around with names, different ways of setting up the template receiver of the Component, etc.

## What I want to ask

Does anyone have any experience with the usage of dynamic components as for the situation I am trying now? I was hoping on a push in the right direction on how to fix the issue of the component being rendered at the right location but without the attributes available.

Comment: If you initialize the variables with a default value in the VoteComponent, and then try to set them after creating it, does it work? e.g --->  public pk: number = 0;  public model: string = ' ';  <---

Comment: Also be aware that when creating dynamic components, they are created as a *sibling* to the ViewContainerRef used to place them. Not as a child. So if you're using ViewChild to place them in a component element, it will be rendered right after that container, not within it. This caused me a lot of confusion when i first started working w/ dynamic components !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research, testing failing and trying some more - I've found it a solution. I'm not 100% satisfied yet, since it becomes a little less dry and organized - but for now:

First I had to adjust the way of passing my data to the dynamically generated component. I had to update my selector target to accept the required attributes. In my case `model` and `objectId`.

```
<vote-component-container [model]="'project'" [objectId]="projectId"></vote-component-container>
```

To link this data to the `VoteComponent`, the `VoteComponent` itself needs `@Input` setters for these data inputs like:

```
import { Input, Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'vote-component-container',
    templateUrl: 'vote.component.html',
})

export class VoteComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    // Temp public for testing
    public _objectId:number;
    public _model:string;

    public constructor(){}
    public ngAfterViewInit(){
        this.getVotes();
    }

    @Input('objectId')
    set objectId(objectId:number){
        this._objectId = objectId;
    }

    @Input('model')
    set model(model:string){
        this._model = model;
    }

    public getVotes(){
        ...
    }
}
```

and eventually in my parent component, I expected the params['id'] section was when the function was called in the ngAfterInit. But it did not, so I had to wait for the promise..

```
@ViewChild('voteComponentContainer', {read: ViewContainerRef}) target: ViewContainerRef;
private factoryVoteComponent(){
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
        this.model = 'project';
        this.projectId = params['id'];

        let voteComponentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(VoteComponent);
        this.voteComponentRef = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(voteComponentFactory);
        this.voteComponentRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    });
}
```